# Mat sum function in multithread using concurrent vector

Tags: c++, opencv, concurrency

I tried to sum the images from multiple threads and created a pixel-by-pixel average function when images are added up to a particular coordinate as number of threads.
so, I bring concurrent vector address to each thread. then each thread overwrite in vector[thread_num].

for example I want to make this

```
thread 1 image result
1 1
1 1  
1 1
1 1
thread 2 image result
3 3 3 
3 3 3
3 3 3
thread 3 image result
5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 
5 5 5 5

result image want to make....
3 3 8 5
3 3 8 5
3 3 8 5
1 1 0 0
```

just do average in intersect part about all thread's image.
and do sum in another part not yet all thread covered.

this is code I tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
#include <concurrent_vector.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>



std::vector<cv::VideoCapture> cap_v;
void makePanorama_th(int thread_num, concurrency::concurrent_vector<cv::Mat>& pano_vector)
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    std::string window_num;
    window_num = std::to_string(thread_num);
    cv::VideoCapture cap1;
    cap1.open("test1.mp4");
    cv::Rect cut(30, 31, 50, 200);
    while (true)
    {       
        cap1 >> frame;
        frame = frame(cut);
        frame.t();
        cv::waitKey(100);
        pano_vector[thread_num].push_back(frame);
        
    }
}

void showPanorama_th(int thread_num, concurrency::concurrent_vector<cv::Mat>& pano_manager_v)
{
    std::string window_num;
    window_num = std::to_string(thread_num);
    while (true)
    {
        if (!pano_manager_v[thread_num].empty())
        {
            cv::imshow(window_num, pano_manager_v[thread_num]);
            cv::waitKey(100);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    concurrency::concurrent_vector<cv::Mat> pano_manager_v;
    std::cout << pano_manager_v.size();
    std::vector<std::future<void>> threadpool;
    std::vector < std::future<void>> showpool;
    cv::Mat result_pano;
    pano_manager_v.push_back(result_pano);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cv::Mat th_pano;
        pano_manager_v.push_back(th_pano);
        threadpool.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, makePanorama_th, i, std::ref(pano_manager_v)));
        showpool.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, showPanorama_th, i, std::ref(pano_manager_v)));
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, one threadpool do fill thread's result to shared vector, another threadpool do show each thread's result by vector.
And I'm going to make a function that performs matrix averaging in concurrent_vector.back() by the minimum width in all thread result images.

so my question is...

1. Is there any better way to calculate Mat array from multiple threads?
2. Is there any difference between concurrent vector and vector with mutex?. In addition, when I first tried do this, I reference multithread queue and using this(https://codetrips.com/2020/07/26/modern-c-writing-a-thread-safe-queue/) and get result image one by one.
3. I still don't know how current_vector works and ensures concurrency. How does this vector ensure concurrency?

Comment: Why not simply use [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) with parallel execution policy?

Comment: I didn't even know that function was in std until I heard from you. 
I think I should learn a little more about std that supports parallelism and then post the question again. Thanks you

Comment: How can this code changed if I implement parallel calculations using std:reduce?