# parallel processing for C+11's vector

Tags: c++, opencv

When I try to do average images input a vector asynchronously(for example, concurrency::concurrent_vector<cv::Mat>), How Can I parallelize sum about points or batches(1 row or 1 col or 3*3 array) of the same coordinates or Area?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to calculate the values in vector in columns or batch rather than in single units(ex. nested for).

**(Edit)**

```
For example 
If I have 3 thread for image processing, and Each result are
thread 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
and thread 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
2 2 2
thread 3
6 6 6
6 6 6
6 6 6

then, just I want is 
3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3


I thought two way for calculate average all thread's image.


 1. just sum each thread result derivered to main thread and 
       count how much result derivered.


If thread1&2 result derivered to main thread.
(1) sum
3 3 3
3 3 3 
3 3 3

(2) save count of sum and coordinate
In this example, save value will
1 - count of sum
Rect(0, 0, 2, 2) - coordinate to nested area

(3) If all thread's result coming, do average about nested area
9 9 9
9 9 9
9 9 9
if count of sum value is 2, find nested area and do average.
2(count of sum) / Rect(0, 0, 2, 2)
result will be
3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3

2. Just wait all thread's result derivered and do average in batches.
like

1|1 1
1|1 1
1|1 1

2|2 2
2|2 2
2|2 2

6|6 6
6|6 6
6|6 6
|
9
9
9
|
3
3
3
```

1. But, I don't know how to access and calculate by Memory References each thread's images. If thread 1 image address (in this case, 0,0 pixel data address in image) is 100, and thread 2 image address start is 200. then  (0,0) pixel data in result images  will calculate *100+*200.

Of course, before doing this operation, I will have to check that the memory matching the coordinates has the correct value.

2. And, Who told If I use std::reduce, will easy to implementation about this.
   But, I have no idea how to apply that function in this way.

Comment: could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz  I'm sorry that my question is ambiguous. I modified it again.

Comment: I found your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768563/mat-sum-function-in-multithread-using-concurrent-vector) which is very similar to this one. the biggest problem is the language barrier. perhaps an english site isn't the best option for you. perhaps automatic translation from your native language would give a clearer description.

Comment: Yeah..I felt that my English skills were not good enough to speak my problems in here. I'll look for a question similar to my situation by looking at other answers. Thank you for your kindly answer.